# Form Post Sends values via Request.QueryString instead of Request.Form

Tags: c#, html, forms, post

Here is an extract of HTML from within a standard HTML page:

```
<form name="login_form" action="http://localhost/BOB.WebPortal/LoginForm.aspx" method="post>
        <div id="content_logins">

            <div id="spacer_ie" style="width:990px; height:7px; border:none; float:left"></div>
            <div style="width:255px; height:22px; border:none; float:left"></div>
            <div style="width:172px; border:none; float:left; vertical-align:bottom">
                    <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" size="13" /></div>
                <div style="width:110px; border:none; float:left">
                    <input type="password" name="pword" id="pword" size="13" /></div>
                <div style="width:140px; height:22px; border:none; margin-top:-2px; float:left">
                    <!--input class="btbgfix" type="image" src="images/submit.png" alt="Submit" value="Login"-->
                <input name="submit" id="loginButton" class="btbgfix" type="image" src="images/submit.png" alt="Submit" value="Login"></div>
            <div style="width:320px; height:22px border:none; float:left">
                <img name="login" src="x.gif" id="alogin" usemap="#m_login" border="0" width="320" height="22" />
                <map name="m_login" id="m_login">
                    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,681,22" href="https://www.aetmyportfolio.com.au" target="_blank" alt="Go to AET My Portfolio" />
                </map>
            </div>  

            </div> 
    </form>
```

My problem is that I am trying to retrieve the post value uname and pword using Request.Form from within the Page_Load event of the C# codebehind file in my ASP.Net application.  However I find that Request.Form is empty.  However if I use Request.Params then I can access the values as they are being passed as query string values in the URL.

Am I doing something wrong in my html?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that's a direct copy-paste from your HTML, you're missing a closing quote on the end of "post".

Comment: You are right.  I couldn't see that one for looking.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working with a standard HTML page for your login control, it does not seem like the runat="server" is going to solve all of your problems.  Here is a quick sample of how I replicated your solution.  It seems to pick up the values correctly.

**Login Page**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="login_form" action="Default.aspx" method="post">
    <div id="content_logins">
            user:<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" size="13" /><br />
            pass:<input type="password" name="pword" id="pword" size="13" /><br />
            <input name="submit" id="loginButton" type="submit" alt="Submit" value="Login">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx**

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Label1.Text = Request.Params["uname"].ToString();
        this.Label2.Text = Request.Params["pword"].ToString();
    }
}
```